# UIView commitAnimations - scale along center

Tags: objective-c, core-animation

I have a UIView that I'm trying to animate.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"scaleAnimation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

CGRect f = self.frame;
f.size.width = f.size.width * 2;
f.size.height = f.size.height * 2;
self.frame = f;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The animation works fine, but is there anyway I can make the animation scale along the center?
Right now, it looks like the point is on the top left corner.

Using CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0); does the animation along the center, but doing a touch event, the points seems to get all messed up when I'm trying to detect transparent area of the UIView.

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple. Animate the `bounds` instead. As [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/bounds) says:

> Changing the bounds size grows or shrinks the view relative to its center point.

So your code would be like this

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"scaleAnimation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];

CGRect f = myView.bounds;
f.size.width = f.size.width * 2;
f.size.height = f.size.height * 2;
myView.bounds = f;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Hey David, so using bounds does have the UIView centered in the end. However, during the animation, the UIView is actually moving weird in that it zig zag before finally stopping at the right location. Any thoughts on what can be causing it? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry no, it shouldn't do that. When I try the above code, creating only a view, setting it background color and animating its bounds it doesn't do that. I would suggest posting another question to get more attention to it and see if someone else knows. Though you will probably have to show more code than this, since the problem probably lies elsewhere. Maybe show how the view is created or manipulated elsewhere prior to the animation.